# htacess file not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have the following htaccess, directory listing is enabled, however when go to the directory the .htaccess file is in, there's no access control. what's wrong?

```
                                                                   
AuthName "Restricted Area"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /home/xxx/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
require valid-user
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is that I need to have `AllowOverride All` to allow `.htaccess` at the directory levels.

```
         <Directory /var/www/vhosts/localhost>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
                 AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `AuthGroupFile` from there, perhaps it is causing trouble.

Everything else looks absolutely correct. One possibility is that your copy of Apache doesn't have the `AuthConfig AllowOverrides` enabled for your files. This would disable `Auth*` entries in `.htaccess`.

Answer (score -1):

You must type to the top: `RewriteEngine On`

If that does not work, that means you may not have `RewriteEngine` at all

Comment: The rewrite engine is actually not used for authentication, it's mod_access rather than mod_rewrite. But AuthConfig might not be enabled in this case for .htaccess files, which is similar to the rewrite engine not being allowed.